# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Sessions#new - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to figure out the following problem. Could someone help me out in the beginning of learning rails?

### Environment

ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

Rails 5.1.4

devise (4.3.0)

### Current behavior

Following result is displayed in browser window after pressing 'Sign up' -link.

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Devise::Sessions#new
>
> No route matches {:action=>"new",
>   :controller=>"devise/flight_records"}

Following code in **application.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Add New', {:controller => 'flight_records', :action => 'new'} %>
<%= link_to 'Logbook', {:controller => 'flight_records', :action => 'index'} %>
<%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path %>
<%if user_signed_in? %>
  <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete  %>
<%else %>
  <%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

Following code in **routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
   devise_for :users
   resources :flight_records 

   #get 'welcome/index'

   root 'flight_records#index'
```

**Following routes in rake:**

rake routes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a new user. so, It should go to devise#registration with POST action.
By default devise signup creates a user record, if you wants to create flight_records, modify the form to point to flight_records create method.

Comment: At this point actually I'm trying to access the Sign Up view with the get action.

Comment: Now I got it up and running. I somehow messed up the usage the usage of the controllers in the application.html.erb, since i didn't know how to use them. Now the code looks like this and it works:  <%= link_to 'Add new', new_flight_record_path %>  
      |     
      <%= link_to 'Logbook', root_path %>
      |
      <%= link_to 'Sign Up', new_user_registration_path %>
      |

      <%if user_signed_in? %>
  
          <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete  %>
      <%else %>
          <%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %>
      <% end %>

Answer (score 0):

Now it works! Working version of the application.html.erb

|     
      
      |
      
      |

```
      <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete  %>
  <%else %>
      <%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path %>
  <% end %>
```